# Can I integrate Peoples app in my android app

Tags: android, android-intent, android-permissions

I am sorry if this is a silly question, actually we are building an app and in our app we are thinking rather inventing the wheel again if by any way we can integrate the "PEOPLE" app (available in android) directly in our application and once user will select any contact number from the launched people app we will get this in our app.

Please help and advice.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot directly integrate another app into your own.

The closest thing to that is to start another app via Intent.

For example, the default camera app in android can't be integrated but it can be called via intent to open the user takes a picture and then the camera app returns to the calling app.

If the functionality you want has been exposed via Intent in the People app then maybe you can do it this way otherwise you have to do it yourself, or maybe there's an open source implementation somewhere to use.

You may be in luck though if I'm understanding what you want is to open Contacts then the user selects a contact and it then returns this contact to your app? If so, [this is what you want](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)